# Execute a command before or after an InSpec test

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

I wonder if anyone has or can create a sample code which demonstrates how to execute a shell script after (or before) InSpec test.

The primary idea is to use RSpec after block to clean up resources allocated during the test run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Overall If you need to cleanup your machine after tests to run next batch it should different test suite or you should destroy and re-converge machine. Do you use test-kitchen for your tests?
- If you need to do anything before InSpec test, it should be part of your converge process. Wrap your normal recipes with code which should be run before test. (preferred way).
- You can 'hack' InSpec and provide your own [sudo_command](https://github.com/chef/kitchen-inspec#usage). (ugly way).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GitLab, then you can use the CI pipeline to do this.  Your `script` section could do any setup required, run the InSpec tests, and then do any cleanup required.

You can find more about GitLab CI here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/